# Undefined Control Sequence in Table Tabularx

Tags: undefined

I would like to create a table in [www.overleaf.com](http://www.overleaf.com)  with compiler pdfLaTeX TeX Live version 2022.

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\captionof{table}{Table of $q$ and $z$}
\label{tab:table_q_and_z}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth} { | c | c | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X |}
  \hline
  \textbf{Steps} & \textbf{$q_i$} & \textbf{Definition of $z_i$}  \\
  \hline
  \multirow{$i \leq (n-1)$}  & $q_i$ = 0 & $z_i$ = number of \emph{emptied} chambers at the \emph{cleaning} place $i \leq (n-1)$ \\
  \cline{2-3}
                  & \centering $q_i$ = 1 & $z_i$ = number of \emph{loaded} chambers at the \emph{processing} place $i \leq (n-1)$ \\
  \hline
   $i=n$  & $q_{n}$ = 0 & $z_n$ = number of \emph{loaded} chambers at the \emph{processing} place $n$ \\
   \cline{2-3}
                & $q_{n}$ = 1 & $z_{n}$ = number of \emph{emptied} chambers at the \emph{cleaning} place $n$ \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

There is an error : "Undefined Control Sequence" as follows.

[image: error]

However the table printed well as follows.

[image: result]

Can anyone tell me what needs to be revised on the code, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this query a near-duplicate of your 2 Apr 2023 query, [Center Aligned in A Cell of Table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/681610/5001)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems.

First, the macro `\captionof` is defined in the `caption` package, but this package isn't loaded in the preamble. Since the `caption` package isn't fully compatible with the `IEEEtran` document class, you are probably doing well not loading it. The remedy? Just, replace

```
\captionof{table}{Table of $q$ and $z$}
```

with

```
\caption{Table of $q$ and $z$}
```

Second, you aren't loading the `tabularx` and `multirow` packages, which define the `tabularx` environment and `\multirow` macro, respectively, which also occur in your test document.

Third, you're not using `\multirow` correctly. It takes 3 arguments, not one.

Fixing these issues and performing some more cleanup -- such as deleting a stray `\centering` directive, deleting the unnecessary `\noindent` directive, and changing `\textbf{$q_i$}` to `$\bm{q}_i$` in the header row -- results in the following output.

Finally, not an error *per se*, but a reasonably salient stylistic issue: The `IEEEtran` document class employs Times Roman as the main text font family, but uses Computer Modern as the main math font family. Times Roman and Computer Modern don't mesh particularly well, aesthetically speaking. You may want to consider running

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

in the preamble to employ mutually compatible Times Roman text and math font families.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx,multirow,bm}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Table of $q$ and $z$}
\label{tab:table_q_and_z}
% \noindent % <-- has no effect
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth} { | c | c | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X |}
  \hline
  \textbf{Steps} & $\bm{q}_i$ & \textbf{Definition of $\bm{z}_i$}  \\
  \hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{$i \leq (n-1)$}  
     & $q_i$ = 0 
     & $z_i$ = number of \emph{emptied} chambers at the \emph{cleaning} place $i \leq (n-1)$ \\
  \cline{2-3}
     & $q_i$ = 1 
     & $z_i$ = number of \emph{loaded} chambers at the \emph{processing} place $i \leq (n-1)$ \\
  \hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{$i=n$}  
     & $q_{n}$ = 0 
     & $z_n$ = number of \emph{loaded} chambers at the \emph{processing} place $n$ \\
  \cline{2-3}
     & $q_{n}$ = 1 
     & $z_{n}$ = number of \emph{emptied} chambers at the \emph{cleaning} place $n$ \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Mico, I changed to: \caption{Table of $q$ and $z$} , however the error remains the same: "Undefined Control Sequence".

Comment: @NicholasTI - Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much@Mico, it worked now.

Answer (score 2):

With `tabularray` package the table code is simple and short:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Table of $q$ and $z$}
    \label{tab:table_q_and_z}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = { *{2}{Q[c, mode=math]} X[j, m, cmd=\hangindent 1.5em\hangafter 1]},
             cell{even[2]}{1} = {r=2}{},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, mode=text}
             }
Step            &   $\bm{q}_i$  &   Definition of $\bm{z}_i$    \\
i \leq (n-1)    &   q_i = 0     & $z_i$: number of \emph{emptied} chambers at the \emph{cleaning} place $i \leq (n-1)$  \\
                &   q_i = 1     & $z_i$: number of \emph{loaded} chambers at the \emph{processing} place $i \leq (n-1)$ \\
i=n             &   q_{n} = 0   & $z_n$: number of \emph{loaded} chambers at the \emph{processing} place $n$    \\
                &   q_{n} = 1   & $z_n$: number of \emph{emptied} chambers at the \emph{cleaning} place $n$         \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or without option `cmd=\hangindent 1.5em\hangafter 1` in the third column specifications:

[image]